# Is there a better way to group by multiple columns in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of attachments that I need to group by clientCLID and EmailAddress. From this grouped list I only need a list of clientCLIDs.

After fiddling for a while I've managed to get it to work as follows:

```
Dim ClientCLIDs As New List(Of Guid)

Dim groupedAttachments = attachments.GroupBy(Function(j) New With {Key j.ClientCLID, Key j.EmailAddress}).Select(Function(group) New With {Key .compKey = group.Key.ClientCLID}).ToList()

For Each attachment In groupedAttachments
Dim clientGuid As Guid = New Guid(attachment.compKey.ToString())
ClientCLIDs.Add(clientGuid)
Next
```

Is there a better/cleaner/easier way to do this? The vb group by syntax is nasty!

**Edit**

I cant just do distinct()...see the following example:

Here I would need client A to appear in the final list 3 times:

```
ClientGuid EmailAddress    

A          b@b.com
A          sds@fdd.com       
A          ieieid@dd.com
```

Here I would only want client A to appear once in the final list

```
ClientGuid EmailAddress
A          bob@bob.com
A          bob@bob.com
A          bob@bob.com
```

Comment: So all you want is a list of distinct `attachment.ClientCLID`s?

Comment: @AakashM apologies - no that isn't what I need, see edit above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the anonymous type inside the selector, and get the list of guids directly:

```
attachments.GroupBy(Function(j) New With {Key j.ClientCLID, Key j.EmailAddress}). _
Select(Function(group) group.Key.ClientCLID).ToList()
```

Here's another approach that does the same thing:

```
(From j In attachments
Select New With {Key j.ClientCLID, Key j.EmailAddress}).
Distinct.Select(Function(client) client.ClientCLID).ToList()
```

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly. The vb linq syntax confuses me!

Comment: Thanks for this example of functional grouping in VB.NET. I was able to perform grouping with lambda notation without issue but couldn't figure out why I couldn't use an anonymous object to group in functional notation. The `Key` reserved word made all the difference.

Comment: Thanks indeed. I had a query working in C# and couldn't figure out why the grouping didn't work when I translated to VB.NET. As said above, `GroupBy(Function(f) New With { Key f...})` is the way to go. Without `Key` the grouping just doesn't work.